# How to change part of selected range in a selection of multiple non-contiguous range

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, multipleselection

I will try to illustrate the scenario by only focus on the problem and take out all the non essential issues/scripts.

User selects multiple non-contiguous cells. VBA would do a few things...then insert a column.
If the selected cells happened to be at the right side of the columns, the content would move one column right of the original selected cells. I need to re-select the cells with the original content before exit sub.

For instance,

1. the user selects "A1", "C3", and "D4:E6".
2. the vba insert a column at "B"
3. now the content of "C3" and "D4:E6" move to "D3" and "E4:F6"
4. I need the vba to select "A1", "D3" and "E4:F6" before exit sub.

I have considered a few methods:

1. Offset the entire selection to one column right.

   `selection.offset(0,1).select`

   This is not a good solution as "A1" would move to "B1". It is only ok if the user selected cells are all at the right side of the inserted column.
2. Put each cell of selection (selected range) into array. Change the affected cells' range. and use vba to select them all again. The problem is that the vba I wrote can't select the entire array of ranges (multiple non contiguous cells) at once. It only selects the last cell in the array. Here is the summarized code:

   ```
   Sub mtArea()

   Dim Cell, Rg, sRg() As Range
   Dim h, i, j, k, noCell, Cnt As Long
   Set Rg = Selection

   noCell = Rg.Cells.Count
   k = 0

   ' assign each cell in selection to a specific array

   If Rg.Areas.Count > 1 Then
      ReDim sRg(noCell)
      For Each Cell In Rg
         k = k + 1
         Set sRg(k) = Cell
      Next Cell
   End If

   ' select the new located cells

   For i = 1 To noCell
    If sRg(i).Column > 5 Then ' assuming insert column is "E"
      h = 1
    Else
      h = 0
    End If
   sRg(i).Offset(0, h).Select
   Next i

   End Sub
   ```

   In this case, only the last cell in the original range is being selected. Is there a way to select the entire sRg() range array?
3. I also hope to explore this way:

   ```
   Dim Rg as Range
   Set Rg = Selection
   ```

   When user selects multiple non contiguous cells, is there a way for vba to change the individual cells range location in the Rg variable?

What should be the method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assign a **Name** to the range, the cells will be adjusted after the column is inserted:

```
Sub RememberTheCells()
    Range("A1,C3,D4:E6").Select
    Selection.Name = "Previous"
    Columns("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("Previous").Select
    MsgBox Selection.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gary's Student, thank you!
This is exactly what I need for my project. Instead of putting the selected range to variable or array, I just need to name it!!  

The selected cells moved with the newly inserted column.
Brilliant! Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just a note, I also need to remove the range name after selecting the range, otherwise this Range Name will continue to exist in the workbook.

      Range("Previous").Name.Delete

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub InsertDemo()
    InsertAndAdjustSelection 2

End Sub

Sub InsertAndAdjustSelection(Col As Long)
    Dim strAddress() As String
    Dim i As Long

    ' Save adresses of selected cells
    strAddress = Split(Selection.Address, ",")

    ' Insert Column
    Columns(Col).Insert

    ' Unpdate saved addresses
    For i = 0 To UBound(strAddress)
        If Range(strAddress(i)).Column >= Col Then
            strAddress(i) = Range(strAddress(i)).Offset(, 1).Address
        End If
    Next

    ' Select range
    Range(Join(strAddress, ",")).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you! 
Your code worked. And you taught me a new way to manipulate range using splitting addresses of selection of multiple cells. Amazing. Definitely valuable lesson. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Both your code and Gary's student code works perfectly well for my situation. However, stackoverflow only allow me to vote for one solution. So I choose the one with lesser lines. :)